# recv() not waiting for data

Tags: c, sockets, networking

On the first iteration of a while(1) loop for communication in a socket, everything works fine - on the second iteration, even though the connection is still open and ongoing (the server's send() waits for the user to insert data, on this same socket), the recv() from the client fails to wait for data.

```
while(1)
                memset(buffer, 0, 300);
                int nRet = recv(sock, buffer, 299, 0);
                printf("Recv: %d\n", nRet);
                if(nRet < 0)
                    fprintf(stderr, "recv() failed.");
                else if(nRet == 0)
                    continue;
                else
                    fprintf(stdout, buffer);
```

This is the beginning of the loop, which is of concern. The output, on the second iteration, is an infinite printing of "Recv: 0". This to me seems illogical - recv() is supposed to wait until data is sent, and none is being sent by the server.

Comment: 0 length recv means the connection is closed or this is UDP and you received a 0 length datagram (seems not the case here)

Comment: https://manned.org/recv.2 "When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the return value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return).

       Datagram sockets in various domains (e.g., the UNIX and Internet domains)
       permit zero-length datagrams.  When such a datagram is received, the
       return value is 0.

       The value 0 may also be returned if the requested number of bytes to
       receive from a stream socket was 0."

Comment: You need to `break` the loop on `nRet == 0`, not `continue` the loop. On a side note: this code is missing `{}` braces on the `while` loop. But more importantly, `fprintf(stdout, buffer);` is just plain wrong. `buffer` is not null-terminated, but even if it were, if it ever contains the character `'%'` then `fprintf()` will exhibit undefined behavior. Use `fprintf(stdout, "%.*s", nRet, buffer);` instead.

Comment: Good recommendation, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the man page on my Linux system,

> When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the return value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return).
>
> Datagram sockets in various domains (e.g., the UNIX and Internet domains) permit zero-length datagrams.  When such a datagram is received, the return value is 0.
>
> The value 0 may also be returned if the requested number of bytes to receive from a stream socket was 0.

So either the connection was closed, or you received an 0-byte datagram. The endless repetition suggests the former. Repeatedly trying to read from a closed connection won't magically reopen it.

What it isn't is an error.

> These calls return the number of bytes received, or -1 if an error occurred.  In the event of an error, errno is set to indicate the error.

A signal interruption results in error `EINTR`. If the socket was made non-blocking and nothing is available, that results in error `EAGAIN` or `EWOULDBLOCK`. You aren't experiencing either of these.